# A given number from 2 to N should have each number divisible outputted as [(2,4), (2,6),( 2,8),( 3,9),( 3,12), (3,15) .....] in Python 2/3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tuples

We have a given number from 2 to N. Each number divisible should appear as below:

`[(2,4), (2,6), (2,8),(3,9),(3,12),(3,15),(4,8),(4,12),(4,16) ...]` upto N 
 numbers.

I tried it myself (see below), but I am not getting the expected output as above (which is the one I want).

```
>>> [(a, b) for a in range(5) for b in range(5) if a%2 == 0 and b  %2==0]
>>> [(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (2, 0), (2, 2), (2, 4), (4, 0), (4, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: Please, clarify your problem with a toy example and the result you want to get. Use correct format to make your question readable. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. Why is (3,6) not in there? What about (3,3)? What is `N` - the largest value for the second number, or number of required outputs?

Comment: yes 3,3  or 4,4 or 5,5 such duplicate not alloweed and 3,6 shud be included .. while typing i missed out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NOTE: Any number divisible by `n` (where `n` is a whole number - `1, 2, 3, 4 ...`) is a multiple of `n`.

You can try:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

multiples = [(a, b) for a in range(2, n + 1) for b in range(2, n + 1) if b%a == 0 and a != b]

print (multiples)
```

where `n` is the number "below" which the number of multiples is printed for a specific number, but using `n + 1` prints the number of multiples "up to" `n` (only if it is possible).

For example, when `n = 10`, it will give this output, `[(2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 10), (3, 6), (3, 9), (4, 8), (5, 10)]`.

This has two conditions: `b%a == 0`, which makes sure that `a` is not zero, as `b / 0 == math error` and `b%a` checks whether the second number is a factor of the first number, or not.

Without `b%a == 0`, you would have:

```
[(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 9), (9, 2), (9, 3), (9, 4), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8)]
```

Since you do not want `a` equal to `b` (`3 == 3`), you can use `a != b`, so don't have to worry about getting `(3, 3)` or `(4, 4)` etc.

To get the maximum number of multiples for a good range of numbers ( `2` to `n`) , I would use a larger sample such as `n = 50`, which will give this output:

```
[(2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 10), (2, 12), (2, 14), (2, 16), (2, 18), (2, 20), (2, 22), (2, 24), (2, 26), (2, 28), (2, 30), (2, 32), (2, 34), (2, 36), (2, 38), (2, 40), (2, 42), (2, 44), (2, 46), (2, 48), (2, 50), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 12), (3, 15), (3, 18), (3, 21), (3, 24), (3, 27), (3, 30), (3, 33), (3, 36), (3, 39), (3, 42), (3, 45), (3, 48), (4, 8), (4, 12), (4, 16), (4, 20), (4, 24), (4, 28), (4, 32), (4, 36), (4, 40), (4, 44), (4, 48), (5, 10), (5, 15), (5, 20), (5, 25), (5, 30), (5, 35), (5, 40), (5, 45), (5, 50), (6, 12), (6, 18), (6, 24), (6, 30), (6, 36), (6, 42), (6, 48), (7, 14), (7, 21), (7, 28), (7, 35), (7, 42), (7, 49), (8, 16), (8, 24), (8, 32), (8, 40), (8, 48), (9, 18), (9, 27), (9, 36), (9, 45), (10, 20), (10, 30), (10, 40), (10, 50), (11, 22), (11, 33), (11, 44), (12, 24), (12, 36), (12, 48), (13, 26), (13, 39), (14, 28), (14, 42), (15, 30), (15, 45), (16, 32), (16, 48), (17, 34), (18, 36), (19, 38), (20, 40), (21, 42), (22, 44), (23, 46), (24, 48), (25, 50)]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @kavi Raj - Does this help answer your question? If not, I was glad to have been able to help you in any possible way :)

Comment: Hi Justin, the attempt is good but  missing number are (2,10),(3,12),(3,15) .. it like i need all the multiples in the given format of tuple inside a list..

Comment: current execution is giving below output.Enter a number: 10
[(2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 10), (3, 6), (3, 9), (4, 8), (5, 10)]
>>>

Comment: @kavi Raj - Try a larger sample of `n` such as 20. It will give you your required output.

Comment: Hi justin     (3,21),(3,24),(3,27),(3,30) are few missing (4,24) ,(4,28)            are also missing...                                                  
     Enter a number: 20
[(2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 10), (2, 12), (2, 14), (2, 16), (2, 18), (2, 20), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 12), (3, 15), (3, 18), (4, 8), (4, 12), (4, 16), (4, 20), (5, 10), (5, 15), (5, 20), (6, 12), (6, 18), (7, 14), (8, 16), (9, 18), (10, 20)]
>>>

Comment: @kaviRaj - It actually depends on how many multiples you want. For your satisfaction, I suggest that you should try - `n` = 100.

Comment: Thanks Justin when N=100 it works well this is what i was looking for. surprising not sure why not working correctly when n < 100. Thanks a lot for sharing ,Appreciate it

Comment: @kavi Raj - For example, let's say `n` = `20`. For each number (`1, 2, 3, 4 ...`), it will only print multiples up to that number, i.e. `20`. Ex. `[(2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 10), (2, 12), (2, 14), (2, 16), (2, 18), (2, 20), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 12), (3, 15), (3, 18), (4, 8), (4, 12), (4, 16), (4, 20), (5, 10), (5, 15), (5, 20), (6, 12), (6, 18), (7, 14), (8, 16), (9, 18), (10, 20)]`.

Comment: @kavi Raj - If you liked my answer, please feel free to upvote or accept my answer. If not, I was glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[(a, b) for a in range(5) for b in range(5)]
```

gives tuples containing all the combinations of pairs of numbers starting from, and including 0, up to (but not including) 5.

`a%2 == 0` is checking for `a` being even. Likewise for `b%2 == 0`, so you are finding tuples of even numbers from the unfiltered list above, hence your output.

If you don't want zero, start at 1, e.g. `range(1,5)` or `range(2, 5)`.
In fact, you need to avoid zeros.
To check the second number is a factor of the first, check `b%a`, having made sure `a` won't be zero.

So more like this:

```
>>> [(a, b) for a in range(2, 5) for b in range(2, 5) if b%a == 0]
[(2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

To avoid (3,3) or other cases add `a != b` to the condition in the list comprehension.

```
[(a, b) for a in range(2, 5) for b in range(2, 5) if b%a == 0 and a!=b]
[(2, 4)]
```

If you then want each second number to just appear once, you can subsequently filter that list.

Comment: basically the numbers should be multiples like 3,15 and 3,18,3,21,3,24 3,27,3,30 is missing